# Tracking time within a smartcard

Tags: smartcard

In the course of my research in the literature of smartcards, I often came across paragraphs citing that smartcards being without a realtime clock has no concept of date or time in any transaction. However, I imagined that an offcard or inspecting client terminal can request a digital time stamp signature in which, the smartcard has the key to verify and therefore securely acquire a sense of time in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It is true, that smartcards lack an independent time reference (due to lack of a power supply enforced by the form factor **card**), so they have to "believe" the outside world.

In passports according to [ICAO specification](https://www.icao.int/publications/pages/publication.aspx?docnum=9303) a scheme was integrated, so that at least the date was kept track of, which the terminal has to provide. (As long as the passport does not encounter any border terminal, nothing will happen.) The are few criteria the card may check beyond correct format and "must be later or equal than my last date" and the generic trusted channel, which ensures uncompromised data and is only achievable by trustworthy terminals.